# How to correct data with Python when there is always and unforeseen bias with DEktak and their Profilometer

Tags: python, numpy, data-visualization, spyder

So I walked over a wafer with a profilometer and it should show a normal wafer "Heidelberg" and a Wafer with newton rings "KIT 4000" so it should show waves in its profile. Unfortunately the original data doesn't show anything.
So I tried to level the data and failed misserably. It looks really ugly and I am at my witsend.
I hope you can help me.

here is my approach:

```
def rough_correct(data,N=2048):

mavg = np.convolve(data[1], np.ones(N)/N, mode='same')

correction = interp1d(data[0],mavg,kind='slinear')

data_corr = np.copy(data)
data_corr[1] -= correction(data[0])
return data_corr  
def correct_baseline(data,cut=0.1,N=256,inv=False):
if inv:
    mask = data[1] > max(data[1]) - cut*( max(data[1]) - min(data[1]))
else:
    mask = data[1] < min(data[1]) + cut*( max(data[1]) - min(data[1]))
#mask = data[1] < cut*max(data[1])

mavg = np.convolve(data[1][mask], np.ones(N)/N, mode='same')

correction = interp1d(data[0][mask],mavg,kind='slinear')

data_corr = np.copy(data)
data_corr[1] -= correction(data[0])

return data_corr
data1=np.genfromtxt(r'C:\Users\Klaus\Desktop\IMS\Edel.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=17,skip_footer=0).T
b = rough_correct(data1,N = 4096*4)
c = correct_baseline(b[:,:-8000],cut=0.5,N=1000,inv=False)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
ab=np.genfromtxt(r'C:\Users\Klaus\Desktop\IMS\nichtEdel4000.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=24, skip_footer=0).T
aa = rough_correct(ab,N = 7000)
d = correct_baseline(aa[:,:-9000],cut=0.38,N=1000,inv=False)
plt.plot(c[0],c[1],label='Heidelberg')
plt.plot(d[0],d[1],color='red',label='KIT 4000')
plt.legend()
fig.show()
```

[here is the original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOihP.png)

[here is the corrected one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00AGt.png)

[here is data the method should also cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8whFr.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need some kind of fit to visualize the data